# How to set default parameters in the index_helper method for rails generators?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, generator

I use the [index helper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.3/classes/Rails/Generators/NamedBase.html#method-i-index_helper) like this

```
= link_to <%= index_helper(type: :url) %>
```

I want to pass default params so the generator creates resource_index_path(my_params).
I looked at the [method definition](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b738f1930f3c82f51741ef7241c1fee691d7deb2/railties/lib/rails/generators/named_base.rb#L97) but couldn't see how to make this work. Is it even possible without overrides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rb
# File railties/lib/rails/generators/named_base.rb, line 97
def index_helper # :doc:
  uncountable? ? "#{plural_route_name}_index" : plural_route_name
end
```

The method isn't doing anything with any variables passed to it.

But, as you'll note, it's just returning a string, so you can freely append to it as you please:

```rb
= link_to <%= "#{index_helper}?name=Bob&age=32&is_admin=true" %>
```

But I'm not sure why you're not just creating [a standard path or URL helper](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers):

```
# edit path:
= link_to <%= send("edit_#{resource_name}_path", all: "the", params: "you could want") %>

# index path:
= link_to <%= send("#{resource_name}_path", all: "the", params: "you could want") %>

# show path:
= link_to <%= send("#{resource_name}_path", all: "the", params: "you could want") %>

# new path:
= link_to <%= send("new_#{resource_name}_path", all: "the", params: "you could want") %>
```

Comment: I think I was just overcomplicating things. The standard path solution you suggested looks like a good route!

Comment: And worth noting that the helpers you were using are private methods for the instance. Private methods on Rails internals are a good sign to just leave them alone and don't plan to use them directly. Rails needs them for something and overriding them or changing them can have bad consequences.